# Generate arrays from a fixed step recursively

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I want to generate arrays recursively based on two inputs:

1) input array, e.g., `double[] in={0.25, 0.25, 0.5};`

2) Step size, e.g., `double step = 0.25;`

The function `foo()` should take those two inputs and generate the following arrays:

`{0.5, 0.25, 0.5} (add step 0.25 to first element)`

`{0.0, 0.25, 0.5} (subtract 0.25 from first element)`

... and so on.

All 2^d combinations (here d=3).
But I want to do it recursively without specifying the dimensions (d).

```
public void foo( double[] inatt, double[] outatt, double step, int d) 
{

   if( d = 0 )
   {
       // should print the array outatt:
   }
   else
   {
      outatt[d] = inatt[d]+step;
      foo( inatt, outatt, step, d-1);
   }

}
```

I do not know how to organize the calls inside the recursive function.. 
I guess if the number of dimensions (d) is not known in advance, then it is the variable I should use to control the calls recursively?

Comment: It sounds like you want to generate an array of arrays?

Comment: Or you want to pass `Consumer<double[]>` to avoid running out of memory.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, he just wants to print each combination without storing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your explanation contradicts with your example. If there are 8 combinations for `d=3`, I assume that you want to combine operations like `(add, add, add)`, `(add, add, subtract)`, ..., `(subtract, subtract, add)`, `(subtract, subtract, subtract)`. However in your example there's `(add, no-change, no-change)` and `(subtract, no-change, no-change)`. I assume that example is incorrect.

I suggest to add `d` instead of subtracting, start with `0` and print when `d == inatt.length` (why `inatt`? `inarr` was meant?):

```
public void foo( double[] inatt, double[] outatt, double step, int d) 
{
   if( d == inatt.length )
   {
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outatt));
   }
   else
   {
      outatt[d] = inatt[d]+step;
      foo( inatt, outatt, step, d+1);
      outatt[d] = inatt[d]-step;
      foo( inatt, outatt, step, d+1);
   }
}
```

The results for your input (`foo(new double[] {0.25, 0.25, 0.5}, new double[3], 0.25, 0);`) are:

```
[0.5, 0.5, 0.75]
[0.5, 0.5, 0.25]
[0.5, 0.0, 0.75]
[0.5, 0.0, 0.25]
[0.0, 0.5, 0.75]
[0.0, 0.5, 0.25]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.75]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.25]
```

If you want something else, please clarify the question (at least provide the full expected output).

Comment: for every element in the array there are 3 cases: add, subtract, no-change.

Comment: Your idea to start with d=0 then add until == inapt.length is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tagir, I found the solution with his helpful code.
I have three cases for every element in the array: add step, subtract step, or no-change.

The recursive call is started from the first element in the array, then continued until reaching the last element.

```
public static void foo( double[] inatt, double[] outatt, double step, int d) 
    {
        if( d == inatt.length )
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outatt));
        }
        else
        {
           outatt[d] = inatt[d]+step;
           foo( inatt, outatt, step, d+1);
           outatt[d] = inatt[d]-step;
           foo( inatt, outatt, step, d+1);
           outatt[d] = inatt[d];
           foo( inatt, outatt, step, d+1);
        }
    }
```

For input array:

```
        double[] att={0.25, 0.5};
        double step = 0.25;
```

This is the output:

```
foo(att, new double[d], delta, 0);
[0.5, 0.75]
[0.5, 0.25]
[0.5, 0.5]
[0.0, 0.75]
[0.0, 0.25]
[0.0, 0.5]
[0.25, 0.75]
[0.25, 0.25]
[0.25, 0.5]
```